# Reset a table using query in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

can here is any reset query which reset the table after update.
I update a colum and then I want to reset it.

```
 id      name
 1       azeem
 2       arfan
```

update the table.

```
  update table set name = 'abc' where id = 1;
  update table set name = 'xyz' where id = 2;

id      name
1       abc
2       xyz
```

**Update:**

```
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from table");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo $row['name'];
   }
```

After that I want to reset it. How can I do that.?

Comment: what do you mean by reset? clear "name" ?

Comment: @mihai reset mean go back to it's original value.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you need to undo an `update`, you'll need to wrap it in a `transaction`, and then you can use `rollback` to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

2 Ways.

If you're running a test server and want to restore back all of the info that you're changing, then you can make a [backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and [restore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html) the table values after the `update`.

otherwise if you're talking about at the transaction level you can make a [transaction and instead of committing, roll it back](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php).

```
<?php
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Change the database schema and data */
$sth = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert
    SET name = 'hamburger'");

/* Recognize mistake and roll back changes */
$dbh->rollBack();

/* Database connection is now back in autocommit mode */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as sgeddes said, you need to use a transaction. When you use a `transaction` which is not `committed` you can `rollback` to the state before the query executed.

Try this:

```php
//Start the transaction
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

//An update query
$yourUpdateQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE YOUR_TBL SET COLUMN = 'COLUMN_VALUE' WHERE COLUMN_ID = ID_VALUE");

//Some SQL select queries (note, that this do not have effect on your data, so this don't need to be in your transaction
$sql = mysql_query("select * from table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $row['name'];
}

//Some check here
if (1==1) {
    //Ok, let's finish it
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {        
    //Not ok, rollback to the state before the transaction started.
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

**Note** that you and the above example are using `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated. You should use `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`.
Here is a PDO example:

```
<?php

    //PDO Database connection (if you haven't done this)
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME', "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

    //Start the transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    //An update query
    $db = $db->exec("UPDATE YOUR_TBL SET COLUMN = 'COLUMN_VALUE' WHERE COLUMN_ID = ID_VALUE");

    //Some SQL select queries (note, that this do not have effect on your data, so this don't need to be in your transaction
    $sql = 'select * from table';
    foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo $row['name'];
    }

    //Some check here
    if (1==1) {
        //Ok, let's finish it
        $db->commit();
    } else {        
        //Not ok, rollback to the state before the transaction started.
        $db->rollBack();
    }   



?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*`? I think you can do better than this.

Comment: True, but the men asked a question based on his current code. He's probably a starter in PHP/MySQL, so if i throw some PDO statements he won't understand the concept (like a lot of people who just use `beginTransaction();`. Is your answer 'better'? Yes, maybe it is, but i don't know if he will understand what you are saying.

Comment: I mean no offense, but If he is a starter then you should point him in the right direction, 1 year ago when `mysql_*` functions really got deprecated I remember that everyone was "spamming" to drop those functions and move to PDO. You can change your code and provide with an alternative way. Leave what you answered and add PDO. He needs to understand and learn sooner than too late. You can use [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) resource to point him.